# How to display "pie chart unavailable" message when all the data is 0 in a pie chart?

Tags: d3.js

So i have made this pie chart in d3 and it seems to work all fine. But i need to display a message when the dataset has all 0 values.
 I have tried to sum all the dataset values and if the value is 0 then append a div with a text message. I am not able to get it right.
Any better way to do this? Need insight.

[Here's the link to my codepen](http://codepen.io/separ1/pen/aBMPGm?editors=1010)

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('barsChart', function () {
var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
     scope: {data: '=chartData'},
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var data =  [
    {label:"Category 1", value:0}, 
    {label:"Category 2", value:0}, 
    {label:"Category 3", value:0}
    ];

   var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                     .range(colorRange.range()); 
  var width = 150;
    var height = 150;
  var radius = Math.min(height,width)/2;
  var labelr = radius + 10;
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
              .sort(null)
              .value(function(d) {
                      return d.value;
                  });
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(width / 2 * 0.9)
      .innerRadius(0);

  var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(Math.min(width, height) / 2 * 0.9);

       var legendRectSize = (radius * 0.05);
   var legendSpacing = radius * 0.02;

    var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
      .attr({width: width, height: height})
      .append('g');
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

            data.forEach(function (d) {
                if(d.value == undefined || d.value == NaN){
                    d.value = 0;
                }

            });

        svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + 200 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');
       svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "slices");
      svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "labelName");
      svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "labelValue");
      svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "lines");


       var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), function(d){ 

    return d.data.label });

slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
    .attr("class", "slice");

slice
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
    })
slice
    .on("mousemove", function(d){
        div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
        div.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
        div.style("display", "inline-block");
        div.html((d.data.label)+"<br>"+(d.data.value)+"%");
    });
slice
    .on("mouseout", function(d){
        div.style("display", "none");
    });

slice.exit()
    .remove();

       var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
        var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
        var horz = -3 * legendRectSize;
        var vert = i * height - offset;
        return 'translate(' + horz/2 + ',' + 90 + ')';
    });

/*legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

var text = svg.select(".labelName").selectAll("text")
    .data(pie(data));
text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return (d.value+"%");
    });

 function midAngle(d){
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
 }
 text
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2),
                x = pos[0],
                y = pos[1],
                h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
           return "translate(" + (x/h * labelr) +  ',' +
       (y/h * labelr) +  ")";
        };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            return (d2.endAngle + d2.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ?
        "end" : "start";
        };
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return (d.value+"%");
    });
  text.exit()
    .remove();
    } 
   };
   return directiveDefinitionObject;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simply showing the text, create a variable to display the text:

```
var message = svg.append("text");
```

And check if the sum of values is zero:

```
if (!d3.sum(data, d => d.value)) {
    message.text("Pie Chart unavailable")
}
```

If you want to create a `<div>` instead of an SVG text element, change the text variable for appending a div (anywhere **but** on the SVG, you can't append divs to an SVG), and keep the `if` statement.

here is your updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqGLLb?editors=0010

Comment: can i set color  and position attributes to this message element as well?....I got it...i just need to append attributes and it works the same way as any other appended element! Thanks

Comment: what is => symbol?

Comment: This is a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: when all the values for the data are 0 ; console throws errors .can i disable the pie chart instead of letting 0's pass and screw up my functions? or append message to the svg?